# Error posting 1.4KB string from Silverlight to WCF Data Service

Tags: silverlight, wcf-data-services

I'm using SL 5 and WCF DS 5. I'm calling a service POST operation where a string is sent as input which is basically contents of a text file. It seems when the string is smaller, it works, but when it is around 1.4KB (size of the text file), this error is thrown:

```
{System.InvalidOperationException: An error occurred while processing this request. ---> System.Exception: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
```

at System.Net.Browser.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Http.ClientHttpWebRequest.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpWebRequestMessage.EndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.HttpTransportLayer.EndGetResponse(IODataRequestMessage requestMessage, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.GetResponseHelper(ODataRequestMessageWrapper request, IAsyncResult asyncResult, Boolean handleWebException)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.AsyncEndGetResponse(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Data.Services.Client.BaseAsyncResult.EndExecute[T](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.QueryResult.EndExecuteQuery[TElement](Object source, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceRequest.EndExecute[TElement](Object source, DataServiceContext context, String method, IAsyncResult asyncResult)
   at System.Data.Services.Client.DataServiceContext.EndExecute[TElement](IAsyncResult asyncResult)

**I called the same operation from a WPF app, and it works fine**. I also did this on the WCF DS host:

```
WebHttpBinding binding = new WebHttpBinding();
        binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferPoolSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.MaxBufferSize = int.MaxValue;
        binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = int.MaxValue;
```

Here is the call from the SL client:

```
CodeFirstContainer context;

        context = new CodeFirstContainer(new Uri("http://localhost:4444/MyDataService/"));

        OperationParameter p = new UriOperationParameter("fileIDN", fileIDN);
        OperationParameter p1 = new UriOperationParameter("**fileContent**", responseContent);

        context.BeginExecute<int>
            (new Uri(context.BaseUri.OriginalString + "ProcessTextFile"),
                (r) =>
                {
                    Deployment.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(() =>
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            context = r.AsyncState as CodeFirstContainer;

                            // Get the response of the query.
                            var response = context.EndExecute<int>(r).ToList();
                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                        }
                    }
                    );
                },
                context, "POST", true, new OperationParameter[] { p, p1 }
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer for my question here:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/adodotnetdataservices/thread/1b9b84cb-916f-4611-a710-dec94ff103ad